# Express 4.x Prepend cookie to static contents?

Tags: node.js, cookies, express

Is it possible to set a cookie to a static content request using Express? For instance I'm trying to append the cookie "foo" to any request that doesn't have that cookie value set, before sending static contents such as index.html.

```
var express = require("express");
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

var app = express();
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(function(req, res, next){
    if(!req.cookies || !req.cookies.foo){
        res.cookie("foo", "bar");
    }
    next();
});
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

My problem is that this flat out doesn't work. I can set a cookie if I add send onto the end, but it either requires a dedicated url call, or terminates the response when thew original intended target was "index.html", then placed towards the front of the router.

```
app.get('/cookie',function(req, res){
   res.cookie('foo' , 'bar').send('Cookie is set');
});
```

Do I need to do something like check every request, set the cookie, and then set a redirect for the same url to get the original indented request (index.html, etc)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks weird:

```
if (!req.cookies || req.cookies.foo)
```

For one, `req.cookies` will always be defined by `cookie-parser`. If there weren't any cookies passed in the request, it will be an empty object (which will evaluate to `true`). Also, it looks like you want to set a cookie *foo* only if it's set already?

I think you want this instead:

```
if (! req.cookies.foo) {
  res.cookie(...);
}
```

Comment: Ooops. I meant to write "if(!req.cookies || !req.cookies.foo)" just in case the cookies object wasn't set by default.

Comment: @seiche in that case, it should work (and it does for me). You should check with your browser's devtools (or with a tool like cURL) to check the response.

Comment: Yeah, I re-tested my code and it worked. Not exactly sure what the issue with my browser was.